# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and RSS/Atom and Velocity?

Tags: wso2, rss, esb, atom-feed, wso2-esb

I would like to find out if/how it is possible to access/read RSS and Atom feeds from WSO2 ESB. I also would like to know if/how Velocity templating engine is supported by ESO2 ESB.
Thanks.

Comment: They have a connector for that now for esb 5.

Answer (score 1):

For reading and creating RSS or Atom feeds, you can use Feed Host Object in WSO2 Mashup Server. You can find more information in this [documentation](http://wso2.org/project/mashup/2.3.2/docs/feedhostobject.html). If you explain more about your requirement of using Velocity in the ESB, you'll be able to get help I think.